# One queue connect by two channel and multi consumer Rabbit MQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rabbitmq

I have implement RabbitMQ for my system running on ASP.NET. I have a question need to answer to solve my issue.

For a queue that is bind to 2 exchange and listened to by two consumers. Each exchange and consumer are generated from 1 different connection(Exchange_1 and consumer_1 created in connection_1. Exchange_2 and consumer_2 created in connection_2). How can I send that queue to the exact consumer I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to send the `queue` anywhere. You have to make both of your `exchanges` bind to the `queue` and both the `consumers` subscribe to the `queue`.